# github desktop not allowing sync to remote repository - no access or repo deleted or renamed

Tags: github, synchronization

We are having an issue with syncing on Github Desktop.

We have a team of 4 members and a company setup in Github.
One of our members can sync the repos he has already worked on before but when I create a new repo for our company, so all members can access it, I can sync but one of the members who is working on the project keeps getting an error

```
https://github.com/companyname/reponame.git/ doesn't seem to exist any more. 
You may not have access, or it may have been deleted or renamed
```

I have tried to research this but not been able to get any direction, where to go?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you everyone for posting and helping.
I have found the solution and it's a big oversight on my part.. Remember when you create a Repo with team member access, you MUST give then access to WRITE as Git sets default to READ only. When syncing, git desktop does not make it clear that its a permissions issue..
[Here is where the READ/WRITE permissions are located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otQnF.jpg) on the Github site once you are logged in.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that:

- the right account for that user has been [added as a collaborator for your repo](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/) (or your [GitHub organisation](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization/)).
- said user is not using a [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) which would have cached another GitHub account

  ```
  git config credential.helper
  ```